# JQuery UI Tooltips: Strange CSS Image formatting

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am annotating my blog by making portions of the text, tooltips that when you hover you see an associated image(http://www.reidcovington.com). There is a strange issue, however, which is that:
A) anytime you hover over a tooltip the image first get displayed improperly almost off screen 
B) the last tooptip you have hovered over gets appended to the bottom of the page so that there is a random image in the bottom left corner of the page.

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( document ).tooltip({
    toggle:   'fade',
    content: function(){
    var element = $( this );
    var title = element.attr( 'title' );
      return '<img src="/assets/' + title + '">';
      }
    });
});
```

Here is a relevant piece of HTML:

```
<span class='tooltip' title='twocats.jpg'>"No. I have 2 cats."</span><br>
```

-I am using title attribute to dynamically show the appropriate image for each tooltip.

Here is my CSS:

```
.tooltip {
/*color: coral;*/
background-color: #dbe9ff;
/*border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.tooltip:hover {
background-color: #dfdbff;
color: white;

}

.ui-tooltip {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Anyone else heard/seen this problem? Any thoughts as to why this might be happening or better practices with tooltips so that it doesnt or a work around that they know works for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code !

Comment: You can see my fiddle here: <http://jsfiddle.net/reidcovington/92rG3/>, but I'm not sure how helpful that is going to be as the asset doesnt load correctly. If you hover over any of the tool tips on this post <http://reidcovington.com/jekyll/update/2014/07/01/who-is-the-real-cat-man/> you can see what I'm talking about though...